# C Block selector key combo?

Tags: visual-studio

So for my C class the professor is asking us to select a block of code(Block Selection). I've spent a bit researching and can only find how to select whole functions(like main). He wants us to select a block of code(the heading, which is all commented). Does anyone know how to do this? And by selecting I mean not control + up, I mean selecting the whole block in one shot.

Thank You so much in advance!

Comment: It is dependent of the IDE you are using.

Comment: This question is not related to the language but the tool you are using, which was unspecified.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. File itself is a Visual 32 Console Application.

Comment: C , C# , and C++ Are **not** the same thing . Please don't spam other tags , Thanks :-)

Comment: Revise your question please. Class dont exist in C language...

Comment: But I'm not asking a question on the code itself...I'm asking a question on code formatting.

Comment: Peter : Formatting? Then I don't understand your questions clearly..

Comment: Is there such a thing as a block selector? Like some sort of key combination in Visual Studio that selects a block of code?

Answer (score 0):

Keep you cursor either at the starting or at the ending braces.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>.

You will find the complete code block is  being selected.

Taken from [here](http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/08/19/how-to-select-a-block-of-code-in-visual-studio/).

Comment: I already knew about that from my research. I'm trying to select a non-function block, like a heading which is commented.